# WPF Load different Animation on the Main Window by Combobox Selection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to upload in a Visual Basic 2010 WPF Mainwindow different Path animation selecting the name of the animation listed in a combobox.
So in a WPF I have my Main window containing a combobox with at this point 2 names in, and I have also Window1 and Window2 each one with a different PathAnimation.
I Do not know how load Animation 1 or Animation 2 in the Main window when the program is running.
I am a little lost

Comment: Basically I have on default the Main window Blank with just a Combo box inside and by selecting Names in the ComboBox load inside of the Main window Animations (Racetrack)that are compiled in other Windows1, windows 2 etc...

Comment: You had the right idea with your earlier question using UserControls. Create a container object in your Window and just swap the proper track in/out depending on your Combobox

Comment: ok I have my container that is an elementhost window is it better to put the combobox in the winForm or in the user control window?

Comment: I would put the combo box in the main form

Comment: ok I tried to have a combobox in the Main window form But I can't find the way to load different track depending by my combobox should i use data source in the combobox properties?

Comment: Try creating a different usercontrol for each track then use the Combobox to load the proper track

Comment: ok I can set my combobox with my names of the track to keep it easy I have two names: Daytona and Austin. but I can't find a command that if the name selected is Daytona for example load up into the element host the Daytona Animation,...I tried both of the way creating different user control or creatind different windows in the user control library and load the windows containing the two track in the main window, i can't make it right.

Comment: containing one of the two track i meant

Comment: I just added an answer with one way to do it. See if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example that I threw together, it is using a ViewBox as a Container. See if this works for you

**MainWindow.xmal**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="697" Width="697" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Name="TrackContainer"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Viewbox>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="360,600,240,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" Name="ComboBox1" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged" Margin="41,600,514,35">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Daytona" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="SecondTrack" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="None" />
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.vb**

```
Class MainWindow 
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Select Case CType(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString
            Case "Daytona"
                CType(TrackContainer.Child, UserControl1).runPathAnimation()
            Case "SecondTrack"
                CType(TrackContainer.Child, UserControl2).runPathAnimation()

        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        Dim cmbox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        Select Case CType(cmbox.SelectedValue, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString
            Case "Daytona"
                TrackContainer.Child = New UserControl1()
            Case "SecondTrack"
                TrackContainer.Child = New UserControl2()
            Case "None"
                TrackContainer.Child = Nothing
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I can't understand it says UserControl 1 and UserControl2 not defined

Comment: I will try to work on it, but I do not understand why it doesn't see the two user

Comment: imported also VWpfControlLibrary1
Imports WpfControlLibrary2
Imports System.Windows.UIElement